# Tricky order of the initialization

Tags: java, initialization

I'm not novice in java, but I've got an example that made me confused.
Here it is:

```
class A {
    public A() { System.out.print("O"); }
}

class B {
    { System.out.print("A"); }
    public B() { System.out.print("D"); }
}

class C {
    static { System.out.print("3"); }
    public C() { System.out.print("P"); }
}

public class D extends C {
    private A objA = new A();
    private static B objB = new B();
    public D() { System.out.print("T"); }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new D();
    }
}
```

So what is the result in system.out?
We know that static members are the first, so "3" will print first cause it is in the superclass and `private static B objB = new B();` will initialize after it (instance initializer and then constructor).

We get `3AD` in console.

Then the main method runs and create a new instance of class D, its ok.

But since this step the order is strange:

**1** Constructor of the superclass `public C() { System.out.print("P"); }`

`3ADP` in console.

**2** Then field of D.class private A objA = new A();

`3ADPO` in console.

**3** And constructor of D.class is the last, so:

`3ADPOT` in console.

So the question is: why does superclass constructor run before field of subclass? I thought that constructors have lowest priority. Can anyone share a link on docs plz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply if we think then its easy to understand that first the subclass inherits from the super class and then only can it override the behaviour or acess the properties defined in the super class.

Whenever we create an object of a class `A` , first it is checked if the class is loaded, if not then it is loaded which invokes its static initilizer if it is present, then all the static fields are initilized (with default value or the values defined). After this super constructor is called, all the properties as set by the super class are set. Then all the instance fields are initilized and then finally constructor code of `A` is executed.

Below is the execution ordering.

```
public class A{
    static{ 
       // 1
    }
    int x = 30; // 3
    public  A(){
       //4
    }
}

public class B extends A{
    static{
        //2
    }
    private int s = 60; //5
    public B(){
         //6
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
       new B();
    }
}
```